# Salesforce SSO and SimpleSAMLphp - Assertion OK, Login failed

Tags: php, single-sign-on, saml

I am trying to setup SSO between a LAMP website and SalesForce by using SimpleSAMLphp v.1.13.2. I have followed this tutorial:
https://salesforce-developer.net/salesforce-sso-with-simplesamlphp

SAML Validation seem OK:

```
Unexpected Exceptions
  Ok
1. Validating the Status
  Ok
2. Looking for an Authentication Statement
  Ok
3. Looking for a Conditions statement
  Ok
4. Checking that the timestamps in the assertion are valid
  Ok
5. Checking that the Attribute namespace matches, if provided
  Not Provided
6. Miscellaneous format confirmations
  Ok
7. Confirming Issuer matches
  Ok
8. Confirming a Subject Confirmation was provided and contains valid timestamps
  Ok
9. Checking that the Audience matches
  Ok
10. Checking the Recipient
  Ok
  Organization Id that we expected: XXXXX
  Organization Id that we found based on your assertion: XXXXX
11. Validating the Signature
  Is the response signed? true
  Is the assertion signed? true
  Is the correct certificate supplied in the keyinfo? true
  Ok
12. Checking that the Site URL Attribute contains a valid site url, if provided
  Not Provided
13. Looking for portal and organization id, if provided
  Not Provided
14. Checking if session security level is valid, if provided
  Ok
```

But assertion was failing as my Subject was a long chain of characters:

```
Subject: cad124bc2458f519d153ffac8699233dc1e1757b
Unable to map the subject to a Salesforce.com user
```

Implementing fix for attributes known from https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gpzrAAA didn't help.

Hardcoding NameID in PHP libraries (modules/saml/lib/IdP/SAML2.php, line 910)

```
        $nameId = array(
            'Format' => $nameIdFormat,
            //'Value' => $nameIdValue,
            'Value' => 'some-uid-1',
            'SPNameQualifier' => $spNameQualifier,
        );
```

helped only for the assertion:

```
Subject: some-uid-1
AssertionId: _a84cac5c11dcc07a4afc4899ea873c5548f63b1cd5
```

, but I still receive an error "Your login attempt using single sign-on with an identity provider certificate has failed. Please contact your salesforce.com administrator for more information.".

What I am I doing wrong? Anyone setting up SimpleSAMLphp with SF recently?

Thank you in advance!
Grzegorz

---

EDIT:
I found an error in the Login History "Invalid Portal Id", to which I found an answer on this page:
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009BSdIAM
Tweaking "AssertionConsumerService" from metadata did the job.
There is a mix with login pages for Communities and standard SF which can be a consequence of adding new domain and login page from the tutorial.

Still, there is an open question - why SF can't decode assertion?